# Sharethis Twitter share image not loading

Tags: django, twitter, sharethis

When using Sharethis to share a post from my website, the Twitter share button is unable to grab a dynamically generated image for the post. I have also included the link to the image in the head with "twitter:image" but the problem seems to persist. Any idea how to go around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an example of metatags to twitter in Django:

in between  place:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Place your card description here"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Card TITLE here"/>
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{{SITE_PROTOCOL_URL}}{% static 'location of the image in static files' %}"/>
```

where SITE_PROTOCOL

```
context = {
   'SITE_PROTOCOL_URL': request._current_scheme_host,
}
```

In this [LINK](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) you can find the twitter card validator debugger

the content url for twitter:image in this example would be:

https://your-site.com/media/your_image_name.jpg

Hope I could help.

Note that will only work in a "live web" context

Comment: Do the images have to be stored in order to use or do urls to the images also work?

Comment: stored in some url. I don't really know if it needs to be in "your" site. My guess Is that you can.